# BroadcastReceiver not working on os 2.3.6?

Tags: android

I'm working on my app that trigger the phone boot(finish boot), When I tried on samsung galaxy s2(ICS) the broadcastreceiver received the receiver on boot but on galaxy y or galaxy pocket with 2.3.6 os version it doesn't trigger the broadcast receiver.

Please help.

Edit here is my receiver in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


 <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiverMessages" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: do you have elements in the logcat related to this?

Comment: Sometimes, the broadcast receivers which gets triggered on boot, gets called after loading of SDCARD is done. Have you checked whether it receives the notification after this event?

Comment: I'm sorry sir I do not have the logcat because the galaxy pocket and galaxy y is not my property and I just tested in school my mate phone, but on my galaxy s2(ics) its working fine.

Comment: @Shrikant sir I have a timer 2 minutes delay before calling my method on broadcastreceiver but broadcastreceiver itself does not trigger. I checked already sir.

Comment: Have you registered your BroadCast Receivers? Please see this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: @Shrikant yes sir I already registered my receiver. actually my app is working fine on galaxy s2(ICS) however it doesn't work on galaxy y and galaxy pocket.

Comment: Few this to test: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in manifest. also, the app must be in internal storage, not on SDCARD.
To enforce this use android:installLocation="internalOnly" in the manifest

Comment: @yoah I thought the default storing system is in sdcard? I will try your suggestion sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I used 2 receivers on my app and I put a delayed time to my boot receiver the low end phone(like galaxy y and galaxy pocket) has a 10 seconds max of delayed time only and it will not trigger if the delay time is more than 10 seconds,

I used handle run delay to my app. thanks to all who commented in this topic.